# GridView or Repeater or something else?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to figure out what's the best tool for the job. A GridView or a Repeater or maybe something else entirely?

I have a table which I want to display, however, depending on the language the user is browsing the site in (French or English), there are certain column I wish to show/hide. I will also have to do some paging as well.

So, my question is which tool would be a better fit for what I need?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GridView because it has all you need.

You can hide rows like this:
YourGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false

It has paging built in!

Comment: See... I tried using a GridView and I was having a hell of a time hiding those columns I wanted. When I did YourGridView.Columns(0).Visible = false, I'd get an "Out of range exception" or something like that?!

Comment: You are probably using the wrong Event. Try using PreRender event of the Page. This is run when everything is created & databound.

Comment: hmmm... i don't think that will work... I'll put a new questions for this. Thanks again!